# Is it possible for an Angular component to get duplicated?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have encountered an unexplained behavior with Ionic Angular component/page. The component is used as a page, with sidebar navigation. The context is more complex, there is a Google Map and other services and the problem appears after a certain sequence of actions (enter page, exit page, enter page, do some actions, exit page, enter page -> duplicated view?).

I would like to find out how it is even possible that the timer callback returns the **current id** (correct) while the subscription callback returns the **current id AND one of the previous ids** as it seems to me mind-boggling as there is no way that a subscriber can even be initialized twice within the same instance (null check) and they are unsubscribed on ngOnDestroy().

```
ngOnInit(){
    // get a new id from the service
    this.viewId = this.idService.getViewId();
    this.check();
    this.watch();
}

check() {
    console.log("init check");
    if (!this.timerCheck) {
      let timer1 = timer(0, 1000);
      this.timerCheck = timer1.subscribe(() => {
        // here everything looks normal on each page entry
        // only the current viewId is shown
        console.log("view id check: ", this.viewId, new Date().getTime());
      });
    }
}

watch(){
   if (!this.locationSub) {
      // the service returns a BehaviorSubject
      this.locationSub = this.locationMonitor.getLocationObservable().subscribe((data) => {
        if (data !== null) {
          // here it happens that the previous viewId is shown 
          // even if the previous component instance has been destroyed (hopefully?)
          console.log("view id watch: ", this.viewId, new Date().getTime());
        }
      });
    }
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.locationSub.unsubscribe();
    this.timerCheck.unsubscribe();
}
```

[Update 1] If I show the viewId in the html, it shows the correct id, but when e.g. I click on a button and call a function in the component, the context is wrong (`this` points to a previous instance). Regardless of what could be the trigger for this bug, I find this raises some weird fundamental issues with Angular such as: how can a previous instance of the page become a "zombie" and somehow (it seems) "restored from the garbage collector" and shadowing the current instance.

Comment: This sounds like a race conditions. You might be making some assumptions on the getViewId maybe? Is that an async call? Can’t tell but I don’t see a sub for it. There really isn’t enough info here to make an assessment I’m afraid.

Comment: The getViewId() function is not async and just returns a variable that is incremented each time

Comment: So is the id you get back there one of the id’s that is sometimes incorrect?

Comment: Yes, there is sometimes shown one of the previous ids (that was obtained within a previous instance of the component) in the console.log messages

Comment: And it's also true that every other instance variables (not just viewId) are "confused" with those of previous instance

Comment: Just as a heads up. Even though you destroy subscriptions (good!), your observables in services keep on living. And a (early) subscribe to a behaviorSubject will always emit the last value it has. Not sure if that's part of the problem.

Comment: check if `ngOnDestroy` is really called. It could be that you need to use a custom routeReuseStrategy

Comment: Maybe use ionViewWillLeave instead of ngwilldestroy or beside implementation of ngoninit, also add ngondestroy since if you didn't put it in class, it will take as a normal function and not angular based function.

Comment: The `ngOnInit` and `ngOnDestroy` functions are called as expected. I find that the problem appears after doing specific (always the same) actions including the google map, which does not make the fundamental problem less weird though.